# I'm trying to use amazon sp-api and get the information about reports but it giving me error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

we are trying to use amazon sp-api and get the information about reports but it gave us error

> Error: [{'message': 'Access to requested resource is denied.', 'code': 'Unauthorized', 'details': ''}]

we configured roles policies and users and also register application but its still give us same error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/authorization-api-use-case-guide#step-2-exchange-the-lwa-authorization-code-for-an-lwa-refresh-token
You need to get a new LWA Authorization code to make your request; it is only good for 5 minutes.